# How to pass a value list to a Tomcat 7 Filter?

Tags: tomcat

I want to pass a value list to a filter definition in web.xml and read it in the filter from the `FilterConfig` object. Something like this:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HTTPWhiteListMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-methods>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </http-methods>
</filter-mapping>
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can do that is to pass a <select your delimiter of choice> separated init parameter.